# why random model response for X decile is fixed at X%?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-models, data-mining, validation

I was reading online tutorials on lift and gain charts [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-gain-chart-and-lift-chart/), [here](https://medium.com/dataman-in-ai/how-to-determine-the-best-model-6b9c584d0db4), [here](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Ebusiforc/Lift_chart.html)

In all of these tutorials, I read or see that random model curve is drawn with the expectation at each Xth decile, we get X% response. X can range from 1 to 10.

For ex: In decile 1, response rate using random model is 10%. In decile 2, it is 20%, 3rd decile it is 30% and so on.

Why not 15% or 5% response for random model at 1st decile?

[image]

Comment: Do you know what the definition of "decile" is?

Comment: yes, divide the population into 10 equal groups.. but why does random response rae also have to be equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This result follows from the definition of decile. Here's a definition of "percentile" from Casella & Berger's *Statistical Inference.*

> For any number $p$ between 0 and 1, the $(100p)$th sample percentile is the observation such that approximately $np$ of the observations are less than this observation and $n(1-p)$ of the observations are greater.

(The word "approximately" is present because there are two corner cases. In the presence of ties, it may not be possible to uniquely order all observations, and therefore there are alternative methods to divide the sample. There are different conventions for what should be done in this case, but that's not enormously important here. A second corner case arises from having a number of observations that can't be divided exactly into groups of sizes $np$ and $n(1-p)$, and there are different conventions for that situation, also.)

The purpose of this chart is to compare how much of the positive response you can obtain using the model compared to baseline of a random selection. The baseline model is randomly assigning each respondent a unique random number $x_i$ (e.g. an integer from $1, 2, ..., n$ or uniformly from [0,1], but this is not consequential - as long as the values are unique, we can sort them uniquely, and order statistics only care about sorting).

Now that we've assigned each sample a random $x_i$, we can sort them. From our definition of percentile, we have $p=0.1$, so the first decile has 10% of the data, and the second decile has 20%, and the third decile has 30%, and so on. Because the data can only be sorted 1 way, we don't have to worry about ties. *In expectation*, the number of positive responses in each decile must create a diagonal line, because we're averaging from among all orderings.

The chart shows that the model is an improvement over the random baseline because at each decile, more positive responses are obtained.

Comment: thanks for the help. upvoted.

Comment: Wow. this is what I was looking for... Some formula like you have given in quoted text.. I know decile means divide into 10 groups but didn't know in detail about below and above limits..